# How do I load files with ModelicaSystem in OMPython?

Tags: python, openmodelica

I have a Modelica model that calls other functions, written in other files for modulation. When I use OMPython to create a ModelicaSystem object using the following:

```
from OMPython import ModelicaSystem  
model = ModelicaSystem("MyModel.mo", "MyModel")
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Class MyFunction not found in scope MyModel (looking for a function or record).
```

MyModel uses in some of his equations other classes and functions, such as `MyFunction`, but I don't know how to load `MyFunction` and the other files the model uses in order for MyModel to be instantiated.

I tried to use the `ModelicaSystem` object constructor on the functions first, but I get:

```
Cannot instantiate MyFunction due to class specialization FUNCTION.
```

I tried loading the files using `OMCSession()` but it doesn't work.
Every file is in the same directory.

How can I load the files to solve the problem?

Comment: To make sure what is wrong modelling and what is an OMPython problem, you could try to do the same from OMEdit. And, just in case, here is a link to the OMPython documentation: https://openmodelica.org/doc/OpenModelicaUsersGuide/latest/ompython.html#import-as-library

Answer (score 0):

You can try coding as follows:

```
from OMPython import OMCSessionZMQ
omc = OMCSessionZMQ()
model_path=omc.sendExpression("getInstallationDirectoryPath()") + "<Modelica file path>"
from OMPython import ModelicaSystem
mod=ModelicaSystem(model_path + "FileName.mo","ModelName")
```